# Jest Puppeteer - Setup Visual Studio Code for it

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, jest-puppeteer

I'm planning to setup env for testing in Visual Studio Code IDE.
The problem that I have is that VS Code in any XXX.test.js file don't know what is `browser` or `page` variable. I'm receiving such errors:

```
'page' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)
```

Is this something related only to IDE that I'm using? Some plugin from this IDE? Or maybe it is normal for `jest-puppeteer` and I need to get used to it?

The whole test when it runs works ok but it seems that IDE only don't know what is `page`.

I'm working right now on this simple example and I'm just learning this but I'm trying to setup env for it in the same time. My `Network.test.js` file looks like this. No imports or require at all at the top of the file.

```
describe("Google", () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await page.goto("https://google.com");
    });

    it('should display "google" text on page', async () => {
        await expect(page).toMatch("google");
    });
});
```

Later I need to switch it to Typescript which I think will be also a challenge. Now I just want to focus on pure javascript approach.

How to get rid of this IDE errors that are not errors in reality?

Answer (score 5):

Add the Puppeteer globals, Page and Browser, to your ESLint config.

Then, add the following to your `.eslintrc` file:

```
env: {
    jest: true,
},
// Puppeteer globals
globals: {
    page: true,
    browser: true,
},
```

See Here : [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-puppeteer/v/1.0.0#configure-eslint)